# Insert bulk data using Openrowset

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

I need to insert datas from a table of database A into another table belonging to the database  B. using Openrowset concept

```
INSERT INTO TableName
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'SQLNCLI', 'Server=(local);Trusted_Connection=yes;',
                         'SELECT Columns FROM ``Database.Schema.Tablename ORDER BY columns)
```

Comment: I want to know whether I can proceed with the above piece of code or I need to add something on top of it

Comment: Ugh, why openrowset? Just use `OPENQUERY`.

Comment: Are the databases on the same server?

Comment: Assuming that both DBs are on the same server then you can just do this: `insert into ThisDB.dbo.ThisTable select * from ThatDB.dbo.ThatTable`. This is documented in the documentation for the ['FROM' clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx).